# How to address the DolphinDB error: The function [nullFill] expects 2 argument(s), but the actual number of arguments is: 1?

Tags: null, metaprogramming, dolphindb, sql-null

For the following script, DolphinDB reports the error: `The function [nullFill] expects 2 argument(s), but the actual number of arguments is: 1 .`

```
sqlCol(zfill_col, nullFill(0), zfill_col))
```

How to address this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DolphinDB, the *func* parameter of `sqlCol(colName, [func], [alias], [qualifier])` accepts a unary function with no arguments, but the function `nullFill` is binary. You can use a partial application to fix the value of the second argument of `nullFill` as 0. My script is listed as follows:

```
zfill_col = `col0`col1`col2
sqlCol(zfill_col, nullFill{, 0}, zfill_col)
```